# How to convert mouse coordinates into world coordinates

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, ray-picking, mouse-picking

#### What I want to do

Picking an object.

#### Requirements / Conditions

- My mouse is always in the center of the screen.
- Pick only the first / nearest object

#### What I want to know

How can I convert my mouse coordinates (actually 0,0 since the mouse is locked to the mid) to world coordinates?

How do I get the actual view direction?

#### What I think I have to do

pseudo code

```
int mx,my = convert(Mouse.getX()), convert(Mouse.getY())
int mz = ??
int dx, dy, dz = ?? # direction of view
drawRay(mx, my, mz, 
        dx, dy, dz + 10) # 10 shall be the range to pick

# later check for intersections
```

Comment: camera position + camera direction + fov + aspect ratio + near plane + basic geometry

Comment: In your case, it might be worth checking out [color-based mouse picking](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL_Selection_Using_Unique_Color_IDs). Otherwise, take a look at the [source code of gluUnproject](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluProject_and_gluUnProject_code)